# Hooks are not rendering in React at all

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I'm building an e-commerce website. Now, I'm working on creating the navigation bar that has the names of the available categories, and once a category is checked (clicked). All the items that have that are listed in the specific category will render in the same page. Right now, I'm working on rendering the names of the products. Here is my code for each part which are navigation bar, all items page, item card.

```
function NavBar() {



// To fill the tabs for the navigation bar
useEffect(() => {

    fetchQuery(`
    query{
        categories{
        name
        }
    }
    `).then(data => {

    var count = 1

    data.data.categories.forEach(categories=> {

        //                     <input className='radio-category' id='all' type='radio' name="nav"/>
        //                     <label for='all' className='category-label'>  <h3 className="tab-text">ALL</h3> </label>

        const input = document.createElement('input')
        input.className = 'radio-category'
        input.id = categories.name
        input.type = 'radio'
        input.name = 'nav-categories'
        // input.onclick = function (){
        //     console.log(input.checked, input.id)
        //     AllItems()
        // }
        input.href = '/'


        const label = document.createElement('label')
        label.htmlFor = categories.name
        label.className = 'category-label'


        const categoryLabelText = document.createElement('h5')
        categoryLabelText.className = 'tab-text'
        categoryLabelText.innerHTML = categories.name.toUpperCase()

        // put categoryLabelText inside label
        label.append(categoryLabelText)

        // render all elements to the nav bar
        document.getElementById("leftNav").append(input)
        document.getElementById("leftNav").append(label)

        // check the first element always
        if (count == 1){
            input.checked = true
            label.checked = true
        }

        count += 1

    })


    })
})

// for currency options
useEffect(() => {

    fetchQuery(`
        query{
          currencies
        }
`).then(data => {

        const selectBox = document.getElementById("currencySelector")

        data.data.currencies.forEach(currencies=>{

            const option = document.createElement('option')
            option.value = currencies
            option.innerText = getSymbolFromCurrency(currencies) + currencies
            selectBox.append(option)

        })

    })
})


return (
    <nav id = "NavBar">
        <div id="NavBar-content">

            <div className = "leftSide" id = "leftNav">

                {/*<input className='radio-category' id='all' type='radio' name="nav"/>*/}
                {/*<label for='all' className='category-label'>  <h3 className="tab-text">ALL</h3> </label>*/}


            </div>

            <div className = "centerSide">
                <a href="/">
                    {/*<img src={logo} />*/}
                    Logo
                </a>
            </div>

            <div className = "rightSide">

                <select className="currencySelector" id="currencySelector">

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

All Items page, which is the container of all the items

```
    function AllItems(category) {

    // useEffect(() => {
    //
    //
    // },[])

    fetchQuery(`
            query{
            category{
                products{
                  name
                  id
                  category
                }
              }
            }
    `).then(data => {

        // console.log(data.data)
        data.data.category.products.forEach(products => {

            // console.log(products.name)

            if ( document.getElementById(products.category).checked ){

                <ItemCard itemName={products.name} id={products.id}/>
            }



        })

    })

    return (
        <div className="itemCard" id="itemCard">

        </div>
    )
}

export default AllItems;
```

Item card container

```
    function ItemCard({itemName, id}) {

    return (
      <>
          <a href='/${id}'>
              <h6 id="item-name">
                  {itemName}
              </h6>
          </a>

      </>
    );
}

export default ItemCard;
```

I don't know why nothing works with me. Is there any missing function or something? Please let me know.

Comment: In react you rarely have any need to use DOM methods like `createElement`. I would recommend using the useEffect/ fetchQuery calls to save that data in a `useState` hook, then use that state to render the required elements in your return

Comment: Also if you ever do want to access the DOM, using `getElementById` should be avoided, and using `useRef` is the preferred way.   https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @seedBoot I know thet `createElement` wouldn't be a good idea in react, but what made my code not working?

Comment: @AsemShaath in your Navbar component, the created elements aren't being appended to the DOM. In you `allItems` function the fetchQuery cannot be used to render JSX. Likewise a forEach won't return a value. As I wrote previously, you'll want to use the `useState` hook to store the data fetched from the fetchQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comments, here's a contrived version of what you may do:

```js
function MyComponent({ checkedCategories }) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    myFetchFunction()
      .then(data => {
        setProducts(data.products)
      })
  }, [])

  const productsToDisplay = products.filter(
    product => checkedCategories.includes(product.category)
  )

  return (
    <div>
      {productsToDisplay.map(product => (
        <SomeProductComponent key={product.id} product={product} />
      ))} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

Separating fetching of data, setting of state, transforming data and rendering are best separated to give a clearer picture of your intent within the component. I hope it's abstract enough to give you something to work on for all your pages.